# How to download iframe video with Jsoup?

Tags: java

Is it possible to download videos in `iframe` tag with Jsoup in Java?

For example `iframe` tag in this [link](http://www.aparat.com//video/video/embed/videohash/rzKus/vt/frame) is :

```
<iframe src="http://aparat.com//video/video/embed/videohash/rzKus/vt/frame?showframe=yes" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%;height: 100%"></iframe>
```

I want to find a way to download this video as mp4 or SWF or other possible formats

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the code below to fetch and process the iframe with jsoup. But you need to know the content to fetch the video link.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element frame = doc.select("iframe").first();
String relHref = frame.attr("src");
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(relHref).get();
```

Comment: "But you need to know the content to fetch the video link" can you explain it more ?What kind of content? thanks

Comment: An iframe shows content from a page. So if you follow that link you need to figure out where on that page your video resides. Then again what format it comes in can't easily be handled but there might be video libraries like ffmpeg that could help there.